# How to map traffic from 127.0.0.1 to Kubernetes Ingress Controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am trying to install and setup kubernetes on My System without any public Cloud Provider.

**What i tried**

I am able to create services and access them through ingress controller ip

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.102.16.16     192.168.49.2   80:30548/TCP,443:31812/TCP   109m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.108.137.156   <none>         443/TCP                      109m
```

this is my ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: odoo-ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: myservice.local.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: "/"
        backend:
          service:
            name: test-service
            port:
              number: 80
```

my hosts file contains

```
192.168.49.2    myservice.local.com
```

and i am able to access my service and deployment at **myservice.local.com** successfully.

**What i want:**

```
public internet --> Ingress Controller --> Kubernetes Services
```

i want that my ingress controller listen on 127.0.0.1 and in the hosts file it should be

```
127.0.0.1    myservice.local.com
```

I want this because i want to access this cluster from public internet. I am not using any public cloud provider for kubernetes.

Comment: If you want to access this cluster from public internet, isn't public IP what you want ingress to listed to?

Comment: yes, ingress should listen on my public ip. but it is not doing so

Comment: Have you tried accessing the ingress from different host? Does that remote client use myservice.local.com to access ingress?

Comment: You are using minikube?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov yes i tried to acces from different pc. but i am unable to access my pc ( on which kubernets installed )

Comment: @Sekru yes i am using minikube, i enabled ingress addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minikube runs on virtual machine so in your machine there is another virtual machine with kuberentes. Ingress works but only when you are on your machine. You can't access inside kubernetes because there is no proxy between your host and virtual machine.

```
public internet ->>> your machine ->>> virtual machine ->> ingress controller
```

**Switch to microk8s(no virtual box)** or create nginx proxy on your machine and formward all requests to virtual machine with your kubernetes.

Comment: Or run minikube with `--driver=none`